# Convert from ByteArrayInputStream to BufferedInputStream in Java InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a program where the user chooses a filepath that is getting passed as a string.

Now I have a function that should create a BufferedInputStream taking that string and assigning it to a InputStream.

```
try (final InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(pathToFile) ) { ...
```

My problem here is that I am getting a ByteArrayInputStream instead of a "normal" BufferedInputStream. If I print the variable "is".

Is there a way to guarantee that it has to be a BufferedInputStream or can I cast to a BufferedInputStream?

I also tried this:

```
try (final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pathToFile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) ) {
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);`

Comment: `BufferredInputStream` constructor takes `InputStream`, can you explain issue here?

Comment: Why does your code care if it receives a BufferedInputStream or a ByteArrayInputStream or whatever type of InputStream? Because in general, it shouldn't, so unless there is a specific reason for this, change your code to accept `InputStream` instead.

Comment: As an aside, I don't know what this `IOUtils` is, but you may want to consider switching to `java.nio.Files.newInputStream` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I dont know if that might be a workaround but:

```
    try (final InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(pathToFile) ) {
        final InputStream xs = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

Works for me. XS is a BufferedInputStream now.

Answer (score 0):

you can get input stream as below

```
try(InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathToFile)))
```